# How to decode hash512 (Excel sheet password)?

Tags: excel

I have to modify a hundred files in Excel (2010)
but unfortunately, the sheets are locked and I don't have the password.

I followed the method which allows you to change the .xls extension to .zip, I opened the archive then
when I open the sheets (.xml), I obtain the following information.
Is there a method that would allow you to find the password based on the information below:

```xml
<sheetProtection 
  algorithmName="SHA-512" 
  hashValue="WXNL2a6LY2R9a3RMvnDzjWH1lufRKhB2zVX4mE+whEvi+u5hPOZ6rRzeSiH1HSakJMJyzyDh3jXfFnAdrkJ6cg==" 
  saltValue="6EMvftltHBwmjBsweAFUaw=="
  spinCount="100000"
  sheet="1"
  objects="1"
  scenarios="1"
/>
```

Comment: Copy sheet xml out of archive, delete this part of code, drop back modified xml to archive and rename archive back to xlsx. Password will be removed

Comment: Yes indeed that's what I had already done but to avoid doing this manipulation on each file, I wanted to know if there was a way to recover the password in plain text

Comment: apparently it is not possible to decode??? but otherwise where is the password saved (in an Excel database?) when the sheet is locked?

Comment: Password is not saved anywhere only its hash which you attached